# Problems starting R with command line

Tags: r, macos, homebrew, zsh, openblas

I am trying to execute R on the command line on macOS using zsh. When I use the command r, I weirdly get the following:

```
$ brew info openblas
openblas: stable 0.3.9 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]
Optimized BLAS library
https://www.openblas.net/
/usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.9 (23 files, 119.7MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2020-03-10 at 14:48:00
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/openblas.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gcc ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
openblas is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides BLAS and LAPACK in the Accelerate framework.

For compilers to find openblas you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include"

For pkg-config to find openblas you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig"

==> Analytics
install: 40,349 (30 days), 89,723 (90 days), 396,666 (365 days)
install-on-request: 3,354 (30 days), 6,545 (90 days), 31,916 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

But R does not start. R was installed using Homebrew.

What's going on here? How do I start R?

Comment: What error/message do you get when R does not start?

Comment: Ok, it seems there was something weird going on. After this, RStudio had also stopped working on startup, despite the fact that it was working just moments ago. I restarted my computer and used Homebrew to update all of my applications. For some reason, despite the fact that I had done this relatively recently, a lot of my applications were apparently outdated. After everything was updated, everything started working again. I have no idea what was wrong in the first place, but it is all fixed now.

Comment: Yeah, that `brew info xx` command does not quite make sense for me in the context.

Comment: @chenrui I did not execute that command (at least explicitly); I executed the `r` command (to start R), and that is what came up. That is the point of this post.

Comment: Cool, understood. Maybe, it worth also posting `brew config` as well :)